# How to convert all url images in page to media library images in wordpress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am really having issue with Conversion of HTML Static Sites to WordPress as images are hosted through HTML SRC Code so after converting it to Wordpress no one is able to see images in Visual Format in Pages during editing so I want to know if there is really any way to convert your whole pages inside images links to media library hosted images so that the person can see the images during editing the page or any alternative solution will be great..!

**Image :**
[image: WordPress Image Not Showing]

Comment: It seems to be due to that image has not full SRC Link so that's why..!

Comment: What errors are there in the console?

Comment: Yes Error is as :
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general there's no way to simply paste your code into wordpress and it grab the images for you, unless you're exporting from a previous wordpress installation or something. You'll almost certainly need to import the images maually using the media buttons available in the editor.

There is a plugin that proports to give the option of importing media from static html files, but I have no experience with it.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/import-html-pages/

Comment: I checked that plugin it's of no use...Bad plugin..! Totally messed the whole HTML imported page..! Only good for very simple HTML structural sites..! not for complex ones..! It changed JavaScript code in head to paragraph..!

Comment: Really there is no auto solution for it?

Comment: @UmarShah From what I've ready that plugin was your best shot, but hopefully someone else will come in with a better solution